# PyQGIS3 retrieving points from a shortestpath graph

Tags: qgis-3, graph, shortest-path, network-analysis

I'm upgrading some code which worked with QGIS 2.18 to now work with QGIS 3.4.5 and had the following snippet working to retrieve a set of points from a graph created by the QgsGraphBuilder function:

```
p = []
while (idStart != idStop):
    l = tree.vertex(idStop).inArc()
    if len(l) == 0:
        break
    e = tree.arc(l[0])
    p.insert(0, tree.vertex(e.inVertex()).point())
    idStop = e.outVertex()
```

(With idStart & idStop being tiedpoints from the graph)

This now does not work, I understand that inArc has changed to inEdges, so my revised code is as follows:

```
p = []
while (idStart != idStop):
    l = tree.vertex(idStop).inEdges()
    if len(l) == 0:
        break
    e = tree.edge(l[0])
    p.insert(0, tree.vertex(e.inVertex()).point())
    idStop = e.outVertex()
```

. However this gives me an error:
 *AttributeError: 'QgsGraphVertex' object has no attribute 'inEdges'*

This seems to contradict the information from the API.

Comment: I cannot see `QgsGraphVertex.inEdges` in the API:https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGraphVertex.html#aaa0ef50f04befc66e756289f743e7f1b. I think what you need to use is `QgsGraphVertex.incomingEdges`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was looking at https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html which gave me the info on edges.  it must be out of date. Your suggestion works for that bit, so I've moved on step..

Comment: Glad it worked. It is better to post an answer to your question so that it will help others and also close the question.

Answer (score 1):

So the QgsGraphVertex has indeed got changes to it. inArc has become incomingEdges, so the information stated in the [https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html][1] is not necessarily correct.